# Loss of significance errors

Tags: numerical-methods

> Give exact ways of avoiding loss-of-significance errors in the
>   following computations:
>
> a. $\tan x-\tan y$, with $x\approx y$
>
> b. $\sin x - \sin y$, with $x\approx y$

I don't know how to do a but for b I derived "$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\sin\frac{x-y}{2}$"  is that correct for question b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a)

$$ \tan{x} - \tan{y} = \frac{\sin{(x-y)}}{\cos{x} \cos{y}} \approx \frac{\delta}{\cos^2{x}}$$

where $\delta = x-y$.

For b), you are correct.